# Почему ссылка не работает?

Tags: php

Прописал в меню ссылки

```
echo "<li><a href='/bol/admin/index.php?&id={$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</a><ul>";
```

Но в при переходе выдает такой путь

> `http://localhost/admin/index.php?id=4`

Почему перешагивает папку bol?

**Дополнено.**

Вот кусок, где пытаюсь проверить нажатие одной ссылки. Может что не так написал?

```
require_once "menu_admin.php";

$id=0;
if ($_GET['id']) $id=$_GET['id'];
if ($id==4){
    $content="Ok";
}
$site=str_replace(array('{CONTENT}','{menu}'),array($content,$menu),file_get_contents("index.tpl"));

echo "{$site}";
exit;
```

Вот ответ мазиллы

> `The link on the http://localhost/bol/admin/ seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of http://localhost/bol/admin/ about the error.`
>
> `If you think this is a server error, please contact the postmaster@localhost`
>
> `Error 404
> localhost
> 09/06/11 22:10:01 Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1`
> и в чем проблема то может быть?

Comment: Посмотрите в код выдаваемой страницы, там href правильный? Если да — а не редиректит ли Вас при переходе на /bol/admin/...?

Comment: .htaccess в студию :-)

Comment: Такого файла у меня нет.

Comment: a href='/admin/index.php?id=2'>   ---- из кода страницы. как видим - неправильный

Comment: Редиректы можно смотреть во вкладке "Сеть" в аддоне файрфокса FireBug.

Comment: А в `index.tpl` что?

Comment: Проблема решена собственными силами. Спасибо всем что были заинтересованы...........

Answer (score 2):

По поводу первого вопроса — видимо, где-то не там написали (в смысле, работает не тот код, который Вы привели), раз выдает `'/admin/index.php?id=2'`. Пропало `/bol/` и пропал амперсанд перед `id`, а чудес не бывает.

Есть, конечно, чисто теоретически, редкий вариант — что вывод чем-то буферизуется и вот так вот странно перерабатывается, но я сильно сомневаюсь в его реальности.

По поводу второго вопроса — вам говорят что URL `/bol/admin/` не существует. Осмелюсь предположить, что, возможно, Вы не на том сервере/vhost'е вообще файлы редактируете? ;) А где-то у Вас лежит старая копия, которую Вам Apache и отдает.

Comment: Вы курите! Амперсанда там и не должно быть! И автор судя по тому, что все таки там есть амперсанд тоже курит!

Comment: Спасибо, не курю. В данном конкретном коде он приведен, значит его можно использовать как зацепку. Точка. Вопрос семантики query string'а меня мало заботит.

Answer (score 0):

У вас выполняется не тот код который вы написали.
Страницу где у вас генерируются эти ссылки в студию.